# resolving the issue coming with text field and button image issue

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I am new in swift.I have created simple login screen .I have two issues coming with loginviewController.swift

Issue 1 # i dont know how to compare the two image that is displayed in button . I have used if checkbox.setImage(img, for: .normal) for comparing image that is displayed in side button for toggle action between checked and unchecked

```
let img = UIImage(named:"check box@1x.png")
    let img2 = UIImage(named:"uncheck box.png")

    @IBOutlet weak var checkbox: UIButton!
    @IBAction func checkbox(_ sender: Any) {
        if checkbox.setImage(img, for: .normal)
        {
        checkbox.setImage(img , for: .normal)
        }
        else{
            checkbox.setImage(img2, for: .normal)
        }
        }
```

Issue 2 # I am trying to high light the bottom borders of text field .i am writing the code for highlighting two text field but it is highlighting only single text field

```
func boaderSetting() {

    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: username_input.frame.size.height - width, width:  username_input.frame.size.width, height: username_input.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    username_input.layer.addSublayer(border)
    username_input.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ///
    let border1 = CALayer()
    let width1 = CGFloat(1.0)
    border1.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    border1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: password_input.frame.size.height - width1, width:  password_input.frame.size.width, height: password_input.frame.size.height)

    border1.borderWidth = width1
    password_input.layer.addSublayer(border)
    password_input.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

how to

->compare image displayed in button with other image

-> hight light the bottom border of both text field .

you can download the project from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zjNUBXZ-9WL4DTglhMXIlN-TpaO5IXBz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check against an image in the button you can use `button.currentImage == image`. In your example it will look like this

```
@IBAction func checkbox(_ sender: Any) {
    if checkbox.currentImage == img2 {
        checkbox.setImage(img , for: .normal)
    } else {
        checkbox.setImage(img2, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

It is only showing a highlight on the bottom text field border as there is a mistake in your example here `password_input.layer.addSublayer(border)`, you want to use `border1` here instead.

```
func boaderSetting() {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: username_input.frame.size.height - width, width:  username_input.frame.size.width, height: username_input.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    username_input.layer.addSublayer(border)
    username_input.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ///
    let border1 = CALayer()
    let width1 = CGFloat(1.0)
    border1.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    border1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: password_input.frame.size.height - width1, width:  password_input.frame.size.width, height: password_input.frame.size.height)

    border1.borderWidth = width1
    password_input.layer.addSublayer(border1)
    password_input.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For #1 you can simply set images for different states.

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageForSelected"), for : .selected)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageForNotSelected"), for : .normal)
```

And then somewhere in your logic set button state

```
button.setSelected(true)
```